# Is there any way to prevent update without where clause in postgresql-12?

Tags: postgresql

In some document I've found there may be a parameter "+bool allow_empty_updates = true;" will solve the problem. 
Here , I want to ask did this parameter really exists in postgresql? How to set this parameter?
Thanks!

Comment: Some SQL clients offer that option

Answer (score 1):

If I remember well - this is a functionality of Postgres extension

https://pgxn.org/dist/safeupdate/

There was a discussion about merging similar functionality to upstream, but I don't remember result, and I don't think so it is there.